# c# calling method with array parameters

Tags: c#

I'm having some problems trying to call a method that has an array as parameters

```
static int inputArray(int[] array)
{
// Method code
  return array[];
}
```

I am trying to call this method in to Main method.
But it is telling me it doesn't exist in the current context.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  inputArray(array);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? also where is `inputArray` defined, and where is `Main` defined? Also where is `array` defined?

Comment: This doesn't even compile...

Comment: If it is telling you that `array` does not exist, it is because you haven't declared it. If it is telling you that `inputArray` does not exist, it is probably because there is some syntax error on the declaration (edit: or perhaps it is in another context, is that in another class you forgot to reference?)... for instance `return array[];` is not making sense to me. In any other clase, please edit your question to make it clearer. I will be voting to close as simple typographical error

Comment: Please show your code. Also, you must define 'array' in your class or method.

Comment: Are you trying to pass the `args[]` array, maybe? To process it?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might not understand the flow of your program or have a misunderstanding about the scope of methods.
The first thing that happens in your program is that Main is ran. 
In the first line of Main() your static method is called with "array" as an argument but nowhere is "array" instantiated, this is why you receive the error about context.

To instantiate "array", new it up in Main()

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] myIntegers = new int[] {1,2,3};
    int firstIntegerInMyArray = inputArray(myIntegers)
}

static int inputArray(int[] array)
{
    // Method code
      return array[0]; // I used zero here, not sure what you are trying to do.
}
```

In your method, you didn't specify an index of which element to return from the given array. In my code I used zero. 
You might want to read up on Arrays and how to use them. [Horse's mouth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.7.2)

A couple other tips are to name methods with a descriptive verb to describe what the method does and to name collections descriptively as well.

Good luck and happy coding!